# how can i adjust the form in navigation bar?

Tags: javascript, php, html, css

I'm create a navbar in my HTML file and when I style it for tablet devices or mobile devices, The form in the navbar won't adjust properly.

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-md">
  <a class="navbar-brand" href="index.php">Login System</a>
  <button type="button" class="navbar-toggler" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarCollapseMenu">
    <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
  </button>
  <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarCollapseMenu">
    <ul class="navbar-nav">
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" href="index.php">Home</a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" href="">Portfolio</a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" href="">About</a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" href="">Contact</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
    <form class="form-inline" action="includes/login.inc.php" method="post">
      <input type="text" class="form-control" name="mailuid" placeholder="Username/Email">
      <input type="password" class="form-control" name="pwd" placeholder="Password">
      <button class="btn btn-primary" type="submit" name="login-submit">Login</button>
    </form>
    <a class="btn btn-warning" href="signup.php">SingUp</a>
    <form action="includes/logout.inc.php" method="post">
      <button class="btn btn-primary" type="submit" name="logout-submit">LogOut</button>
    </form>
  </div>
</nav>
```

Comment: You need to provide some code in order for us to help you!

Comment: Are you using bootstrap css. Share css you use for styling.